# Suggestions to improve code about primes?

Tags: java

I wrote a code about primes and would hear your opinion or any suggestions how i can improve my code. I'm a beginner in Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean a;

    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    int zahl = s.nextInt();

    if(zahl <= 0) {
       System.out.println("Please enter a positive number without zero.");
       return;

    }

    a = true;
    for (int i = 2; i < zahl; i++) {

        if (zahl % i == 0) {
            a = false;
        }
    }

    if (a == true) {
        System.out.println("Is Prim");
    }

    if (a==false){
        System.out.println("Not a prim");
    }
}
```

Comment: Scroll down to `isPrime()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47125814/2970947).

Comment: its perfectly fine I guess you can remove the second if condition and print **not prime** inside loop and break that loop

Comment: I tried what you said. But it always output: is prime. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is the following

Instead of

```
 for (int i = 2; i < zahl; i++) {

        if (zahl % i == 0) {
            a = false;
        }
    }
```

change the for loop the

```
  for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(zahl); i++)
```

If no numbers up to the square root divide zahl, then no numbers beyond the square root will divide it either (they would have been the result of earlier divisions).

Also, for outputing the answer you could do:

```
System.out.println(zahl + " is " + ((a) ? "prime"
            : "not prime"));
```

That's using the ternary operator **?:**

Answer (score 0):

some hints :

You do

```
   System.out.println("Please enter a positive number without zero.");
   return;
```

the *println* suggests the user can enter a new value, but no, in that case better to say the number was invalid so you exit

When you do `a = false;` it is useless to continue, no chance for *a* to be back true

It is useless to try to divide by more than sqrt the number

It is necessary to try to divide by 2 but not by an other even number, so add 2 to *i* rather than 1

If `if (a == true)` false it is useless to check `if (a==false)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good. I have made three small improvements:

- The input asks at once (and not only after a bad input) for a
  positive int.
- The input is repeated until correct.
- The for loop runs only up to sqrt(zahl) which is sufficient.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean a;

    int zahl = 0;
    while (zahl <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive int without zero.");
        zahl = s.nextInt();
    }

    a = true;
    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(zahl); i++) {

        if (zahl % i == 0) {
        a = false;
        break;
        }
    }

    if (a == true) {
        System.out.println("Is Prim");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not a prim");
    }
}
```